# No of common terms in an AP

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find the number of common terms in the following A.P's:
$ 2,5,8..$ up to 50 terms and $3,5,7,9..$ up to 60 terms What I have tried $n^{th}$ term must be equal to $m^{th}$ term so$2+(n-1)3=3+(m-1)2$ so $3n=2m+2$ What next?

Comment: So n must be even. Put n = 2, then m = 2 is a solution. Then put n = 4.  Can you generalise ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$3n= 2m + 2 \implies 3n = 2(m+1)$. This means that $\mathbf n$ **must be even**. 
For smallest $n = 2$, value of $m$ is $2$. For the largest value of $n = 50$, value of $m$ will be $74$ which is not possible. By a few trials like $44$, $42$ and $40$, you'll find that largest value for $n$ is $40$. 
Thus, total common elements are $20$ (for $n=2,4,6,...,40$).